# how to show the max and min from user input?

Tags: python, max, min

Nevermind

```
if xmin == 1:
  print(ymin)
```

I tried using the max and min but I get a typeerror which is 'int' object not iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use min() and max() with integers. It really makes no sense trying to ask a minimum or maximum if computer only has one number to work with. You need to add user inputs into a list like so:

```py
ages = []
ages.append(age)
```

After you've done this you can use min() and max() methods:

```
a = min(ages)
```