# How to use max() and min() for two or three digit numbers from user input

Tags: python, max, min, python-3.8

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum values of a series of numbers inputted by the user. I get only a semantic error, where both the max and min values are the last number inputted by the user.

This is what I have tried:

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    snum = input("Enter a number: ")
    if snum != "done" :
        try:
            largest  = max(snum)
            smallest = min(snum)
        except:
            print("Invalid Input")
            continue

    else:
        break

print("Maximum is",largest)
print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

I used the `try` and `except` block to error check the user input.
I checked other similar questions such as: [How to show max the max and min from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676539/how-to-show-the-max-and-min-from-user-input), but I did not really understand the answer given.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You don't actually use `inum`, or compare to the existing `largest` or `smallest` when you try to update the value. I would also recommend **not** using a bare `except:` or including too many lines in the `try` - be focused about what errors you want to deal with so you can actually see what's going wrong in cases you *haven't* considered yet.

Comment: quick question: why not store all values in a list (better yet, a `set`...) and after all values entered, just use built-in `min` and `max`? Regarding your current approach, you might want to change to `largest  = max(largest, inum)` and `smallest = min(smallest, inum)`

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is here:

```
inum = int(snum)
largest  = max(snum)
smallest = min(snum)
```

You're converting the user value (which always comes in as a string) into an integer and storing it in `inum`. But then you're calling `max` and `min` on the original string value, not the number.

Your second problem is that you are only ever checking one number at a time - `snum` is always filled with the latest number, with other numbers being forgotten.

You need to store each inputted number in a list, and then call `max` and `min` on the list as a whole.

---

Here's a potential solution:

```
num_list = []

while True:
  user = input("Enter a number: ")
  if user == "done":
    break
  try:
    inum = int(user)
    num_list.append(inum)
  except:
    print("Invalid input!")

print("The largest number was", max(num_list))
print("The smallest number was", min(num_list))
```